# Add www when accessing root domain, not using htaccess file

Tags: apache

I have an apache server with some websites built in Wordpress, using vhosts.

The thing is that I have for all of them a configuration like:
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias www.site1.com

When I access to Site1 through "site1.com" the URL changes to "www.site1.com". The same for Site2, Site3, etc. But for SiteN it's inverse. If I access to "siten.com" it keeps the URL and if you go to "www.siten.com" it changes to "siten.com".

I know I can change this using htaccess file, but my doubt is why some sites has a default and the new site has another default? All the htaccess have the same things and the vhost configuration is the same for all.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Done! The change should be implemented in Wordpress configuration, is not a htaccess issue